# Detect button press with the first finger but not if pressed with more fingers Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my **platform game** I have a ball character that is moved by pressing **three buttons**: a ***"MoveRight"*** button to make it move to the right, a ***"MoveLeft"*** to move it to the left, and a ***"Jump"*** button that will give a vertical force to the ball so it will jump.

This is the code i have for the movement control - **everything works as it should**:

**Script *Move2D*:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Move2D : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed = 7f;
    public float jumpSpeed = 7F;
    public bool isGrounded = false;

    public Rigidbody2D rigidbody;

    private Vector2 currentMoveDirection;

    private void Awake()
    {
        rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    public void Jump()
    {
        if (isGrounded)
        {
            rigidbody.AddForce(new Vector3(0f, jumpSpeed), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
    }
    public void JumpHigher()
    {
        rigidbody.AddForce(new Vector3(0f, 12), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rigidbody.velocity = currentMoveDirection * moveSpeed + Vector2.up * rigidbody.velocity.y;
    }

    public void TriggerMoveLeft()
    {
        currentMoveDirection += Vector2.left;
    }

    public void StopMoveLeft()
    {
        currentMoveDirection -= Vector2.left;
    }

    public void TriggerMoveRight()
    {
        currentMoveDirection += Vector2.right;
    }

    public void StopMoveRight()
    {
        currentMoveDirection -= Vector2.right;
    }
}
```

**Script *ContinuesButton*:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ContinuesButton : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler
{
    [SerializeField] private Button targetButton;

    [SerializeField] private Move2D playerMovement;

    [SerializeField] private bool movesLeft;

    private readonly bool isHover;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (!targetButton) targetButton = GetComponent<Button>();
    }

    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        if (movesLeft)
        {
            playerMovement.TriggerMoveLeft();
        } else
        {
            playerMovement.TriggerMoveRight();
        }
    }

    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        if (movesLeft)
        {
            playerMovement.StopMoveLeft();
        } else
        {
            playerMovement.StopMoveRight();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see i am **adding a force every time a button is pressed**. By doing this, i realized that **the player could "cheat" in many ways**.

In the platform there are quite a lot of obstacles that are very hard to pass, because **the speed is just enough**. By pressing with two fingers on the same button, I would **add double horizontal force to the ball**, and it would go **twice as fast**, and **pass the level much more easily**.

Also, in some cases, the player has time to **jump twice** and **go much higher** than how it would normally be.

How can i avoid these two problems?

**Any help or even any little information is really appreciated!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way that should fit into your current approach would be to add a bool field in this script that tracks if the button is currently being held. Something like `private bool buttonHeld;`

Whenever `OnPointerDown` is called and `buttonHeld == false`, set it to true and call your commands, otherwise do nothing. And for `OnPointerUp`, if `buttonHeld == true`, set it to false and do your movemement stop.
And for safety, in `void OnDisable()`, set it to false.

Comment: Thank you. I will try that!