# Problem trying to detect button press with one finger when pressed with more - Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

> ***Extension of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57984983/detect-button-press-with-the-first-finger-but-not-if-pressed-with-more-fingers-u) question.*** - here you can also find my code before this new little change.

In my **platform game** I have a ball character that is moved by pressing **three buttons**: a ***"MoveRight"*** button to make it move to the right, a ***"MoveLeft"*** to move it to the left, and a ***"Jump"*** button that will give a vertical force to the ball so it will jump.

To move the character i am **adding a force every time a button is pressed**.  By doing this, i realized that **the player could "cheat" in many ways**.

In the platform there are quite a lot of obstacles that are very hard to pass, because **the speed is just enough**. By pressing with two fingers on the same button, I would **add double horizontal force to the ball**, and it would go **twice as fast**, and **pass the level much more easily**.

Also, in some cases, the player has time to **jump twice** and **go much higher** than how it would normally be.

To try and avoid this problem, i added in the ***OnPointerDown()*** and ***OnPointerUp()*** methods a variable, whose value is supposed to be:

- **0** when **no fingers** are pressing the left and right buttons.
- **1** when **one finger** is pressing the buttons.
- **>1** when **more fingers** are pressing the buttons (even though i would not like this to happen, but have to handle it so that there aren't any bugs or changes in the character's speed).

**This is the code where this is handled**:

```
public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        if (fingersOnButton == 0)
        {
            fingersOnButton++;
            if (movesLeft)
            {
                playerMovement.TriggerMoveLeft();
            }
            else
            {
                playerMovement.TriggerMoveRight();
            }
        }
    }

    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        fingersOnButton--;
        if (movesLeft)
        {
            playerMovement.StopMoveLeft();
        } else
        {
            playerMovement.StopMoveRight();
        }
    }
```

> **Notice:** The fingersOnButton variable is set to **0** on start.

Now, when i **press a button with two fingers at the same time**, it **does not double the speed** (as i wanted), but when i realease it with both of the fingers some force is stuck like if i was pressing the other button (with one finger).

I tried changing some stuff around those two methods, but nothing seemed to work.

**Any information or help on how to fix this is really appreciated!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to always update the counter when a pointer goes up or down and you want to only call `StopMoveX` when `fingersOnButton` goes to 0:

```
public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    fingersOnButton++;

    if (fingersOnButton == 1)
    {
        if (movesLeft)
        {
            playerMovement.TriggerMoveLeft();
        }
        else
        {
            playerMovement.TriggerMoveRight();
        }
    }
}

public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    fingersOnButton--;

    if (fingersOnButton == 0)
    {
        if (movesLeft)
        {
            playerMovement.StopMoveLeft();
        } else
        {
            playerMovement.StopMoveRight();
        }
    }
}
```